# Code forks fine on macbook laptop..but on Imac(Yosemite) I get errors in my shell script

Tags: python, syntax, ffmpeg

I'm still figuring out how to work within the terminal, mainly with FFmpeg at the moment. I have this code running for a while now on my macbook pro (snow leopard I think). It works fine, no glitches whatsover. I just got an Imac (yosemite) and I wanted to install the same code, but now it gives these minor stupid syntax errors - that are not at fault on my laptop! Its seems bizar to me, but maybe it's something I forgot to install .. like a certain library? I've tried to use the same steps as before but ofcourse I might have forgotten about one..

The code will make a clip of 5 seconds on every hour via the embedded webcam, (the hourly notice is being programmed within crontab). This is the shell script:

---

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FNAME=videocapture_`date +"%F_%H_%M"`.mpg
echo $FNAME

/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -t 5 -f avfoundation -i "default" $FNAME
```

---

And these are the erros (I tried to change a few small syntaxes to see if it would stop but it just finds new errors)

```
"SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
Arantxas-iMac:~ arantx$ python /Users/arantx/Documents/terminal\ stuff/camera.sh 
  File "/Users/arantx/Documents/terminal stuff/camera.sh", line 3
    FNAME=videocapture_'date +"%F_%H_%M"`.mpeg
                                             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
Arantxas-iMac:~ arantx$ python /Users/arantx/Documents/terminal\ stuff/camera.sh 
  File "/Users/arantx/Documents/terminal stuff/camera.sh", line 3
    FNAME=videocapture_'date +"%F_%H_%M"`.mpeg 
                                              ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
Arantxas-iMac:~ arantx$ python /Users/arantx/Documents/terminal\ stuff/camera.sh 
  File "/Users/arantx/Documents/terminal stuff/camera.sh", line 3
    FNAME=videocapture_'date +"%F_%H_%M"`.mp4"
```

---

If someone can point something out that I might have missed, let me know!

Kind regards,

Arantxa

Comment: This is obviously a bash shell script. Wy are you trying to run it through python?

Comment: you should run the script as `bash arantx/Documents/terminal\ stuff/camera.sh 
  File "/Users/arantx/Documents/terminal stuff/camera.sh", line 3
    FNAME=videocapture_'date +"%F_%H_%M"`.mp4"`